# I have got an error When i upload sql in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

i have problem when i upload my sql with phpmy admin

```
    Error
    SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit

    SELECT `comment`
               FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__column_info`
              WHERE db_name     = 'sql_route10'
                AND table_name  = ''
                AND column_name = '(db_comment)'
MySQL said: Documentation

#1100 - Table 'pma__column_info' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

this is error when i upload data
i have try  edit in config.inc.php
i give comment in this line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = $dbname;
```

but this not work.
and  i have change this line

```
/* Optional: User for advanced features */
 77     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'dbuser';
 78     $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'dbpass';
```

but not work ,

Comment: What data are you trying to upload — any chance it contains references to the database `phpmyadmin` or table `pma__column_info`?